# What is the name of this cryptography algorithm?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, xor

I found the cryptographic algorithm implemented in “the_cipher_decipher_func” below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string cipher_decipher(const std::string& src, char mask, const char incr, const char mod)
{
    const auto the_cipher_decipher_func = [&](const char c)
    {
        mask = (mask + incr) % mod;
        return static_cast<char>(c ^ mask);
    };

    auto tgt = std::string{};
    std::transform(src.cbegin(), src.cend(), std::back_inserter(tgt), the_cipher_decipher_func);
    return tgt;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;

    auto source = std::string{argv[1]};

    const char incr = 12;   // arbitrary
    const char mod = 50;    // arbitrary
    const char initial_mask = mod / incr;   // arbitrary, but lower than "mod".

    auto mask_cipher = initial_mask;
    auto ciphered = cipher_decipher(source, mask_cipher, incr, mod);

    auto mask_decipher = initial_mask;
    auto deciphered = cipher_decipher(ciphered, mask_decipher, incr, mod);

    std::cout
        << "source: " << source << std::endl
        << "ciphered: " << ciphered << std::endl
        << "deciphered: " << deciphered << std::endl
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

It seems a mix of XOR and incremental key. However, does somebody may identify the precise origin of this cryptographic algorithm?

Comment: where did you find it?

Comment: _"Cesar cipher"_ effectively? An ole one ...

Comment: I doubt it has a name by itself. It's just a Caesar cipher + XOR cipher.

Comment: @user463035818, I found this algorithm it in one of my customer’s source code. Unfortunately, they lose any reference about it.

I looked at [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) with a calculated table of keys. This is the closer I could find.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seriously.

Comment: It sort of looks like a linear feedback mechanism to generate a keystream. Also see [LFSR-based Stream Ciphers](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/Anne.Canteaut/MPRI/chapter3.pdf). You might consider asking [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) or maybe [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Thomas, how the question appear off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

The cipher itself (combining the key stream with the plain text via an XOR) is called a Vernam Cipher (named after its inventor, Gilbert Vernam).

I don't know of a name for this particular method of creating a key stream, though the group to which it belongs has a number of well known names, like "bad", "awful", and "broken".

This example looks particularly problematic. If (for example) `mod` and `incr` were both primes, you'd at least increase the number of characters in the key stream before it repeated. As is, it repeats after a very short time (which lets an attacker find the key stream using less cipher text).